# Disable Memcache from Symfony project on dev environment

Tags: symfony, memcached

```
  memcached:
    class: Memcache
    calls:
            - [ addServer, ['%memcached_host%', '%memcached_port%'] ]
```

This is current code I use in config.yml how can I specify that Memcache not cache data on `memcache->set(`) method on dev envirioment and to works normally on production.

Is there is some kind of flag that can turn off Memcache ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `Memcache` but common approach to cases like this is using separate `config.yml` per environment:

1. Move your current `memcached` entry from `config.yml` to `config_prod.yml` (in production environment `memcached` will work as before)
2. In `config_dev.yml` add similar `memcached` entry but with another class - you might need to create such class, it will probably need to extend `Memcache` class and override methods you want to behave differently (i.e. `set()`).

In this config you will have different `Memcache` classes for different environments and in dev environment your `Memcache` class will be "dummy", meaning not doing anything.

Comment: I now see your answer, but yes I did something similar I will put my solution as  answer below

Answer (score 0):

This is regular config.yml.

```
services:
  memcached:
    class: Memcache
    calls:
      - [ addServer, ['%memcached_host%', '%memcached_port%'] ]
```

I had add this lines in `config_dev.yml`

```
services:
  memcached:
    class: Memcache
    calls:
      - [ addServer, ['%memcached_host%', '%memcached_port%'] ]
      - [ flush ]
```

You will notice that below is added `- [ flush ]` method
It is not kill memcache proccess but clear all stored data making them like expired.

Comment: Rather than throwing away anything useful that may be in cache, why not create a 'fake' memcache service for the dev environment, extending and overriding the Memcache class, but not saving anything, or trying to fetch?